# FLASH_MODE_SINGLE & FLASH_MODE_TORCH functionality interchanged on Samsung S6 edge

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

While implementing Camera 2 API, I discovered that only on Samsung S6 edge `FLASH_MODE_SINGLE & FLASH_MODE_TORC`H functionality are interchanged. If I set `FLASH_MODE as FLASH_MODE_SINGLE`, it acts as `FLASH_MODE_TORCH` and vice versa. How to solve this particular problem as it is model specific as far as I tested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer still pertinent to you but I found this questions without any answer and I would like to help someone in the future.

Probably the problem is on the logic, I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6 to test the camera2 api and it's working perfectly on both, the FLASH_MODE_TORCH keep the flash on during the capture session and the FLASH_MODE_SINGLE lights the place for a moment than triggers a flash light.

For future problems posted on StackOverflow you should add a piece of your implementation so we(the community) can help better.

Here's an example of a capture from surfaceView that I'm using:

```
            if (getContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                if (isVideo) {
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                } else {
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried it on S6 edge? this issue is specific to that device.